# how to declare an object without defining it at the same time in the cpp file

Tags: c++

Class A has two constructors:

```
A:A(int ,bool)
A:A(int,int,bool)
```

I'd like to achieve something like this:

```
if (condition)
   A object(int,bool);
else
   A object(int,int,bool);

proess(object);
```

But as you know there is a problem since the scope of object is only inside the `if...else...`

So is there a way to achieve this, i dont want to put `process()` inside the `if...else...` neither do i want to use `A *pObject`.

I guess in another word, my question is  how to declare an object without define it?

Comment: `A object = condition? A(int, bool) : A(int, int, bool);` if you're lucky copy elision will kick in.

Comment: Consider `std::optional` or the boost alternative

Answer (score 2):

One potential way to do this would be to set up an assignment operator overload

(`A & operator=(const A &rhs);`) in your class and then have this:

```
//have a default constructor and just keep this empty.
A object;

if(condition)
    object = A(int, bool);
else
    object = A(int, int, bool);
```

Comment: That uses the copy/move assignment operator, not the copy ctor.

Comment: Your right, I get those mixed up sometimes.  The idea is still the same though.

Answer (score 1):

You could make a factory function for this purpose, something like:

```
A CreateObject(const bool condition)
{
    if(condition)
    {
        return A(int, bool);
    }
    else
    {
        return A(int, int, bool);
    }
}
```

Then somewhere else in code:

```
A object = CreateObject(condition);
```

Comment: similarly you could use a lambda as your factory function.